# Get new data.frame column name in cbind from a character

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to assign a '`data.frame` column name' from a character that is automatically generated by `R` in a function. I know I could update column names afterwards with `colnames()` but feel I should know how to do it directly.

Example:

```
test <- iris[1:3, 1:2]
i <- 3
hat_char <- paste0("hat", i) 
x <- cbind(test, hat_char = 3:1)
x
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width hat_char
1          5.1         3.5        3
2          4.9         3.0        2
3          4.7         3.2        1
```

**Hoped-for output**

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width hat3
1          5.1         3.5    3
2          4.9         3.0    2
3          4.7         3.2    1
```

This seems hard to search for due to an avalanche of related but different and more basic questions.

**EDIT:**
Forgot to mention but would strongly prefer `base R` solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `setNames` from `base R`

```
cbind(test, setNames(list(3:1), hat_char))
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width hat3
#1          5.1         3.5    3
#2          4.9         3.0    2
#3          4.7         3.2    1
```

If we assign it to the same dataset

```
test[hat_char] <- 3:1
```

---

If we are using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
  mutate(!! hat_char := 3:1)
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width hat3
#1          5.1         3.5    3
#2          4.9         3.0    2
#3          4.7         3.2    1
```

Comment: Perfect. `setNames()` was what I was looking for but `test[hat_char] <- 3:1` wins I guess.